# Mirroring database in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql

When pricipal database is having less changes than mirror database i.e mirror_failover_lsn is greater than mirror_end_of_log_lsn of principal server, the mirroring session got suspended nad couldn't get resumed. Why so? . Now how can I restore my database and how to establish the session again?

Answer (score 1):

What mirroring mode are you using?

Are you saying that you have writeable access to both databases in the mirror?  If so you may be affected by one of these bugs: [978947](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978947),[978791](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978791)

What status is your principal/mirror in?  check this by looking at the `sys.database_mirroring` DMV on each server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these options:

May work
 - Pause/suspend mirroring
 - Backup database and logs and copy backups to mirror
 - Restore backups and logs with NORECOVERY
 - Try and resume mirroring

Will work
 - Remove mirroring
 - Restore latest backup and log files to mirror
 - Re-run mirroring setup